Codeigniter 3 flashdata bootstrap message not showing although data added to database
Making a simple codeigniter 3 web application
where i wanted to add category name to the database through a form but even after submit the set flashdata msg not showing on front end..although i can see data added to table in phpmyadmin
here is my code  views list.php

<?php $this->load->view('admin/header'); ?>

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Categories</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Categories</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->
 <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
               <?php 
      if($this->session->flashdata('success') !=  ""){ ?>
         <div class='alert alert-success mb-3'><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?></div>;
    <?php  }
       ?>
              
             <!--<div class="alert alert-success">success</div>-->
            <div class="card">
               <!--<div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:450px;">
                <h3 class="">Welcome to Codeigniter Web Console</h5>
              </div>-->
              <div class="card-header">
                 <div class="card-title">
                     <form id="SearchFrm" name="searchFrm" action="" method="">
                          <div class="input-group mb-0">
                              <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="" name="q">
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                     </form>
                    
                 </div><!--card-title-->
                 <div class="card-tools">
                     <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/category/create' ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Create </a>
                 </div>
              </div><!--card-header-->
              
              <div class="card-body">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th width="50">#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th width="100">Status</th>
                        <th width="160" class="text-center">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                     
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div><!--card-body-->
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
       
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php $this->load->view('admin/footer'); ?>
 

 

i even tried this code
 <?php if($this->session->flashdata('success') != ""){ ?>
             <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></div>
             <?php } ?>

but that didnt work too
Update
as dontpanic said i have updated my code
Category.php(controller)
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category extends CI_Controller {

   
    //this method will show category list page
    public function index()
    {
     $this->load->view('admin/category/list');
    }
    
    //this method will show create category page
    public function create()
    {
     $this->load->model('Category_model');
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <p class="text-danger">','</p>');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
          //will check category in database
          $formArray['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
          $formArray['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
          $formArray['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $this->Category_model->create($formArray);
          
          $this->session->flashdata('success','Category added successfully');
          redirect (base_url().'admin/category/index');
          
      }else{
          //Will show errors
          $this->load->view('admin/category/create');  
      }
    
    // $this->load->view('admin/category/create');  
    }
    
   //this method will show edit category page
    public function edit()
    {
        
    }
    
    //this method will will  delete a category 
    public function delete()
    {
        
    }
}

Category_model.php (model)
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function create($formArray){
      $this->db->insert('categories',$formArray);
    
  }
   
}


and updated list.php(after tips from vansh patel)(views)

<?php $this->load->view('admin/header'); ?>

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Categories</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Categories</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->
 <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
               <?php 
               $flashdata = $this->session->flashdata('success');
      if($flashdata !=  ""){ ?>
         <div class='alert alert-success mb-3'><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success');?></div>;
    <?php  }
       ?>
              
             <!--<div class="alert alert-success">success</div>-->
            <div class="card">
               <!--<div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:450px;">
                <h3 class="">Welcome to Codeigniter Web Console</h5>
              </div>-->
              <div class="card-header">
                 <div class="card-title">
                     <form id="SearchFrm" name="searchFrm" action="" method="">
                          <div class="input-group mb-0">
                              <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="" name="q">
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                     </form>
                    
                 </div><!--card-title-->
                 <div class="card-tools">
                     <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/category/create' ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Create </a>
                 </div>
              </div><!--card-header-->
              
              <div class="card-body">
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th width="50">#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th width="100">Status</th>
                        <th width="160" class="text-center">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Fashion</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Staus</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-1"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                     
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div><!--card-body-->
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
       
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php $this->load->view('admin/footer'); ?>
 

create.php (views)(where form for adding category is present)

<?php $this->load->view('admin/header'); ?>

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Categories</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/category/index' ?>">Categories</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Create New Category</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->
 <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
               <!--<div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height:450px;">
                <h3 class="">Welcome to Codeigniter Web Console</h5>
              </div>-->
              <div class="card-header">
                 <div class="card-title">
                     Create New Category
                  </div><!--card-title-->
              </div><!--card-header-->
              <form name="categoryForm" id="categoryForm" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/category/create' ?>">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control <?php echo( form_error('name') != "") ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="" name="name" id="name">
                            
                          <?php echo form_error('name');?>
  
                           
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Image</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file border" name="image" id="image">
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="form-group row">
                              <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                      <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="1" id="statusActive" name="status" checked>
                                      <label for="statusActive" class="custom-control-label">Active</label>
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                                   <div class="custom-control custom-radio ml-3">
                                      <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="0" id="statusBlock" name="status">
                                      <label for="statusBlock" class="custom-control-label">Block</label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              
                          </div>
                      
                           <!--<div class="custom-control custom-radio float-left">
                              <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="1" id="statusActive" name="statusActive" checked>
                              <label for="statusActive" class="custom-control-label">Active</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio ml-3">
                              <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="1" id="statusBlock" name="statusBlock">
                              <label for="statusBlock" class="custom-control-label">Block</label>
                            </div>-->
                         
                     
                  </div><!--card-body-->
              
                  <div class="card-footer">
                      <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/category/index' ?>" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
                  </div><!--card-footer-->
             </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
       
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php $this->load->view('admin/footer'); ?>
 


I think the problem is that first you are checking if flashdata is not empty. But, once you retrieved flashdata information, it will be deleted and hence, the next time you try to retireve flashdata to display, it is not there. So, what you should do is that first save the flashdata to a variable (like $flashdata = $this->session->flashdata('success');), and then in the if statement, check if ($flashdata != "") {, and then in the next line, use it like <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $flashdata; ?></div>

hello, I tried that but that didnt work either

100 lines of HTML does not help us understand a PHP/CI/session problem.  Where is the code which sets your flash data?  How is the form submitted, and how do you land on this page afterwards?  Is Javascript involved?  Do sessions work otherwise in your app?  Edit your question, show us a minimum reproducible example.

hello ,i have updated the code with all the pages involved for the form submission,no javascript used for this purpose..sessions do work in my app for login logout..but in this case i tried both logged in and logged out to test this code but nothing worked

You're using $this->session->flashdata('success','Category added successfully'); to set the flashdata - this should be $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Category added successfully'); instead. (Theflashdata function is for reading the flashdata, set_flashdata is for setting it.)

thanks Marleen ..that was the issue indeed in Category.php(controller)

The problem seems to be how you set your CodeIgniter flashdata In your Category.php controller, instead of using
$this->session->flashdata('success', 'Category added successfully');

try using this
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Category added successfully');

and then in the view file use flashdata to retrieve and display flash data

The if condition validates the flashdata message action as true and would be visible in the view after the redirection, therefore the code would be like this
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')): ?>

        <div class="alert alert-success">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
      </div>

<?php endif; ?>

